# Pointer and shadow on infobox google maps v3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to make pointer from infobox to marker and shadow on the map? I googled, found nothing. I know this might be infowindow, I want same for infobox.

Comment: Have you seen [InfoBubble](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/examples/example.html/)?

Comment: I've already made one script with infowindow, realized I can't hide border, then I made another using infobox, realized it can't have shadow and pointer... exelent job google...

Comment: Also it seems to have any documentation for this https://www.google.rs/search?q=google+infobubble+documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. I ended up using a Font Awesome icon:

```
<span class="icon-down-dir"></span>
```

and added color and text shadow that matched the infobox shadow with css:

```
span.icon-down-dir:before {
    line-height: 0;
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    color: #027db9;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Sorry, can't post image but you can see it here: http://s13.postimg.org/4vqk3f0av/2014_07_18_135631.jpg

Comment: It's not so great but it's something. Google should made one comprehensive infowindow lib, they blew it up.